# Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1' argument<s>

Tags: windows, powershell, tls1.2, activeperl, activestate

I'm newbie to web development learning by myself. I'm not a cs student. I'm following a book called HTML5 in easy steps. There is a lesson called "Building input forms" which uses  free Abyss Personal Edition web server and activeperl scripts.
I want to install activeperl on my machine. I'm on windows 8.1. Activestate site doesn't offer .exe file anymore instead it offers cli installation for windows 10. site says windows 8.1 also be supported.
I tried installing their cli program command for windows which is
 `powershell -Command "& $([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/install.ps1')))"`.

Then I got this error message.[screenshot attached]
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyQCg.png)

Then I googled the exception and found that powershell wasn't configured to older versions of windows prior to 2019 to work with tls 1.2.
`https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6873`

Any tips on how to work around this problem???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**:

- The following is an effective solution for getting the *download* of the [target `*.ps1` file](https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/install.ps1) to succeed, but additional problems may surface when the successfully downloaded script is *executed*.
- Indeed, since you're using PowerShell **v4**, script execution failed due to dependence on the **v5+** `Expand-Archive` cmdlet, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69978140/45375) to your follow-up question.

---

**Enable TLS 1.2** as follows, in a `;`-separated statement before the `.DownloadString()` call:

```
powershell -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; & ([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/install.ps1')))"
```

Note: Since you're only using the PowerShell instance for a *single* download known to use TLS 1.2, the above enables TLS 1.2 *only*.

---

If you also had to preserve the originally enabled protocols:

PowerShell v5+ syntax:

```
powershell -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol += 'Tls12'; & ([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/install.ps1')))"
```

PowerShell v4- syntax:

```
powershell -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; & ([scriptblock]::Create((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://platform.activestate.com/dl/cli/install.ps1')))"
```