# Preparing Installer for State Tool Package Manager. . .x Failed

Tags: windows-8.1, tls1.2, powershell-4.0, activeperl, activestate

This is the second part of [the question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967158/45375), related to activestate cli installation on windows 8.1. I have ps V4.0 installed on my machine.
When I run the command suitable for ps V4.0, provided by @mklement0 as an answer to my question, I got another error.
Screenshots are attached as it is a lengthy error message.
[image: screenshot 1]  [image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]
[image: screenshot 4]
[image: screenshot 5]

any idea what is the problem causing this ?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of the error message is simply the *source code* of the script (block) that caused the error.

The last screenshot reveals the cause of the error: The **[`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive)** cmdlet that the script depends on cannot be found.

This is to be expected in PowerShell **v4**, because this cmdlet was introduced in **v5**.

Therefore, the **solution** is to **upgrade your PowerShell installation to v5.1**

- [Download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616).

Comment: I tried to update the answer. But editing time was over. Luckily, I copied whole comment. It works like a charm.... When I downloaded file from the link and run it, a popup message showed up saying i had to install an update which I downloaded interactively. That's it. after restarting, I installed state tool package manager via powershell successfully. You are a life saver. How to mark this query as solved ? But i still get an error when I tried to install activeperl from activestate. This calls for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the product page here: https://www.activestate.com/products/platform/state-tool/ it states to run in a command prompt, not powershell. Have you tried running the installation command from cmd? It also may not work on Windows 8.1 as it only supports Windows 10.

Comment: You are correct. I saw somewhere stated as it was supported. I can run state command from cmd though I  get a message saying it wasn't tested for below windows  10. My bad  :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).